# How do I repair an InnoDB table?

Tags: mysql, innodb, repair

We (apparently) had poorly executed of our Solaris MySQL database engine last night. At least some of the InnoDB tables are corrupted, with timestamp out of order errors in the transaction log, and a specific error about the index being corrupted.

We know about the tools available for MyISAM table repairs, but cannot find anything for InnoDB.

Side note: attempting a table optimize (in my attempt to rebuild the corrupted index) causes the database server to crash.

Comment: Restore from backups. You *have* backups, right?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First of all *stop the server and image the disc*. There's no point only having one shot at this.  Then take a look [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/07/04/recovering-innodb-table-corruption/).

Comment: It seems the link has different content, doesn't it?

Answer (score 27):

stop your application...or stop your slave so no new rows are being added

```
create table <new table> like <old table>;
insert <new table> select * from <old table>;
truncate table  <old table>;
insert <old table> select * from <new table>;
```

restart your server or slave

Comment: Thanks - I found this solution quite useful because it doesn't require the user to restart the server or work outside the MySQL environment

Comment: not sure why, but I had to drop the old table and then recreate it using LIKE instead of running `truncate` in the 3rd step. Fantastic solution.

Comment: Even after truncate, my old table was corrupted. I dropped it and renamed <new table> to <old table> and it fixed everything, THANKS! Note: some rows were lost in the operation....but I guess that they were the corrupted rows, so probably not recoverable in any way

Comment: pretty sure you can RENAME <new table> <old table>;

Answer (score 9):

The following solution was inspired by Sandro's tip above.

**Warning**: while it worked for me, but I cannot tell if it will work for you.

My problem was the following: reading some specific rows from a table (let's call this table `broken`) would crash MySQL. Even `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM broken` would kill it. I hope you have a `PRIMARY KEY` on this table (in the following sample, it's `id`).

1. Make sure you have a backup or snapshot of the broken MySQL server (just in case you want to go back to step 1 and try something else!)
2. `CREATE TABLE broken_repair LIKE broken;`
3. `INSERT broken_repair SELECT * FROM broken WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM broken_repair) LIMIT 1;`
4. Repeat step 3 until it crashes the DB (you can use `LIMIT 100000` and then use lower values, until using `LIMIT 1` crashes the DB).
5. See if you have everything (you can compare `SELECT MAX(id) FROM broken` with the number of rows in `broken_repair`).
6. At this point, I apparently had all my rows (except those which were probably savagely truncated by InnoDB). If you miss some rows, you could try adding an `OFFSET` to the `LIMIT`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution provided by MySQL:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

Answer (score 1):

Simply stopping and restarting the SQL server worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

See this article: http://www.unilogica.com/mysql-innodb-recovery/ (It's in portuguese)

Are explained how to use **innodb_force_recovery** and **innodb_file_per_table**. I discovered this after need to recovery a crashed database with a single **ibdata1**.

Using  innodb_file_per_table, all tables in InnoDB will create a separated table file, like MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

Note: If your issue is, "innodb index is marked as corrupted"!
Then, the simple solution can be, just remove the indexes and add them again. That can solve pretty quickly without losing any records nor restarting or moving table contents into a temporary table and back.

Answer (score -10):

Step 1.

**Stop MySQL server**

Step 2.

add this line to my.cnf ( In windows it is called my.ini )

```
set-variable=innodb_force_recovery=6
```

Step 3.

delete **ib_logfile0** and **ib_logfile1**

Step 4.

**Start MySQL server**

Step 5.

Run this command:

```
mysqlcheck --database db_name table_name -uroot -p
```

After you have successfully fixed the crashed innodb table, don't forget to remove #set-variable=innodb_force_recovery=6 from my.cnf and then restart MySQL server again.

Comment: Downvoting as you clearly have no idea what you are doing. Deleting the ib_logfiles is just inviting yourself into more problems

Comment: In any case: `innodb_force_recovery=6` is **no** fun and should avoided if possible - **always** try lower values first!