# Do I need to manually rebuild a innodb table with massive deletes on MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb, rebuild

I am currently deleting 9 million rows of a table with 11 million incrementally by 200,000 rows per run.

Will I need to manually rebuild the table and indexes or does this happen automatically after every delete?

Comment: I don't understand the question?  Are you under the impression that by deleting rows, you're deleting the table itself?  or are you concerned that your ID column will no longer be sequential (which is normal)?

Comment: I heard that deleting rows from innodb tables requires a table rebuild, does this happen automatically or do I need to do it manually?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to manually rebuild the table, you can do so like this:

```
ALTER TABLE database.table ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: I ran the command and it deleted all but 30,000 of the rows, Why would that happen?

Comment: Is there anything in particular I should be looking for? It's a long list.

Comment: If you are still deleting rows, I would wait until it's complete. Then re-run the alter and see where stand.

Comment: Ok. Just to clarify, are you trying to reclaim disk space, or are you saying that only 30K of the 9M rows were actually deleted?

Comment: I had 11 million rows, 9 million that I wanted deleted and 2 million that I needed.... I deleted the 9 million then ran alter and it deleted 1,970,000 of the rows that I needed.

Comment: How did you delete the rows? If from the mysql command line, what was the count after the delete completed.

Comment: I deleted the rows that matched a certain criteria using phpmyadmin. After it was completed the table showed ~2 million rows.

Comment: Ok, so the delete was successful, and you ran the alter which should have reclaimed some of the space. What is the issue now?

Comment: Before the alter I had the ~2 million rows I needed. After the alter I only have 37,000 rows. Not sure what caused the additional deletions.

Comment: Could the additional deletions be a sign of a damaged table?

Comment: Oh man, that sucks. But the alter wouldn't have deleted any rows from the table. If you do `select count(*) from table`, it really only has 37K rows? Are you sure you aren't looking at some other value through the phpmyadmin interface?

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226172/how-do-i-repair-an-innodb-table

Comment: Yeah, 37k after alter. Sadly, I didn't have a complete backup. Ouch.

Comment: Sorry dude, obviously that was not my intention. In fact I had to confirm with one of the system guys and they confirmed that we run that after a major purge of data on innodb tables.

Comment: No worries mate, this is just a reminder that I should maintain up-to-date backups.

Comment: Im curious why the loss of rows on an alter though. Maybe google around and see if you find anything.

Comment: Did you try restarting the server after the alter?