# MySql error when selecting

Tags: mysql

I have the table smses_in with id and text columns (about 250 000 records), when I do the query

```
SELECT count(id) FROM `smses_in` group by text
```

I get next error:

> 1022 - Can't write; duplicate key in table '/tmp/#sql_3ed_0'.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056786/error-1022-cant-write-duplicate-key-in-table

Comment: `duplcate key ..` on `select` query???

Comment: Yes, exactly, it's wondering

Comment: Can you post your schema?

Comment: http://speedy.sh/46gKf/wordpress.sql

Comment: @VictorBredihin Looks like maybe the table has been corrupted somehow. See here about sorting the table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226172/how-do-i-repair-an-innodb-table It's mentioned at that link but it's worth reiterating that you should be backing up your tables before following any instructions. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but it does not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

you cannot get that error for a select statement
i did a similar query

```
select count(*) from supportContacts group by id
```

you can see at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/24273

possibly there is some other query in your code which is being run at thee same time...

Comment: So, i created table and insert several rows, all works fine. But I need import file(about 250 000 rows), and when I imported this file, my query (SELECT count(id) FROM `smses_in` group by text) broken with erro (1022 - Can't write; duplicate key in table '/tmp/#sql_3ed_0'.)

Comment: http://speedy.sh/46gKf/wordpress.sql link to schema, you can import it to your DB and see my error