# How to recover database from crashed MySQL Server

Tags: mysql

Due to an accident my server has crashed and the website is not working.

Please suggest a solution to recover MySQL data from crashed Server.

Comment: Is the server toast or can you grab stuff from disk?

Comment: This question has really nothing to do with software development...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can recovery your MySQL data from your InnoDB data backup files?
Is it available ?

Comment: Fortunately, I have a database backup, but mostly database has been corrupted.

Comment: Please follow the thread - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226172/how-do-i-repair-an-innodb-table